# Furnace pilot light gas line, any concern with leaving extra length?

Tags: hvac, furnace, gas

Is there any danger or issue, in leaving the furnaces pilot assembly gas tubing, with extra length and being coiled under pilot light?

I replaced the gas line (1/4") in my old furnace pilot assembly.

I did not cut it to length, and it's coiled under the assembly instead, shown in the picture.

[image]

Thank you

Update 1: Added picture of lit pilot light (flash makes light hard to see)
[image]

Comment: Does it really have a pilot light? While many water heaters have pilot lights (since they run all year long), most furnaces haven't had pilot lights in **decades**.

Comment: It does yes, and always on pilot, that is relit manually (without an attached igniter). This is probably an early 80s installed furnace.

Comment: Added picture of lit pilot light showing thermocouple and pilot light (where the gas line connects from the bottom of the pic)